Access non-type template parameter of CRTP derived class from CRTP base class
In the following CRTP code, is there a simple way to access the non-type template parameter N in Base that is exposed by Derived?
template <typename TDerived>
struct Base
{
    int array[TDerived::NValue];
};

template <int N>
struct Derived : Base<Derived<N>>
{
    constexpr static int NValue = N;
};

int main()
{
    Derived<8> derived;
}

The VS2022 throws error: 'NValue': is not a member of 'Derived<8>'
Do I have to use a separate trait struct?
The following code compiles, but the additional N seems redundant:
template <typename TDerived, int N>
struct Base
{
    int array[N];
};

template <int N>
struct Derived : Base<Derived<N>, N>
{
};

int main()
{
    Derived<8> derived;
}

Thanks!
